# typeorm not working with softdeleted records and unique constraint field

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, typeorm, unique-constraint, soft-delete

Im trying to use typeorm softdelete feature , for deleting its fine ,adds a timestamps to deletedAt field but the problem emerges when you have unique field like "username" and you softdeleted it then trying to add another record with the same "username" field value as deleted record . it doesn't accept it ,since its already inserted once and database has no perception of the softdelete . so i tried to add another field making it a composite unique constraint combining "username" with "deletedAt" , in Postgres it seems like Nulls are not being indexed as i expected . so you again might add multiple records with same "username" and same "NULL" value for deletedAt  .
trying to bypass this by assigning a default value of 0 to deletedAt and now i assume the main issue is how to tell typeorm treat 0 same as it treated NULL in getting queries.

Comment: did you manage to get it solved? If so, do you mind sharing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a partial index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_username ON usertable (username)
WHERE (deletedAt is null);
```

[Postgres: Partial Indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html)

Comment: thank you @Edward , nice trick .for those who might come across this question, the where clause is actally  (deletedAt is null) , i appreciate if you edit it . 

* as in typeorm first inserted record with username "foo" has no deletedAt value so its null , as a result of this partial index it is not indexed so the next record with the same username "foo" can still be inserted . this might be true in a case that something like 0 be a default value which eradicate the root of asking this question at the first place .

Comment: @ItsJay - I'm glad it worked - I've updated the answer to be (deletedAt is null)

Comment: Does you know if there is an alternative for mariadb (or mysql)? A orm level solution would be ideal.

Comment: @kb05 I don't know and I do not understand what you are asking. You should create a new question, possibly referencing this one, and state your question clearly.